# English translation of Belgian Patent BE629083 needed

Tags: expired

I need the English translation of Belgian Patent BE629083.
Thank you.

Comment: Try mygengo.com for a first pass.

Answer (score 1):

Google Patents does its very best to automatically translate patents such as this. [Here is that page.](https://patents.google.com/patent/BE629083A/en?oq=BE629083). Unfortunately the [original document](https://worldwide.espacenet.com/patent/search/family/000198698/publication/BE629083A?q=pn%3DBE629083Achannel=espacenet_channel-17ec937a-e2a7-4c65-8aa0-fed9f152447e) is a very poor scan of a poorly printed and very technical document with symbols. It is possible that with Google's translation and your reviewing the original you might be able get a grasp of its content. Otherwise, you may need to rely on a fluent French speaker to help.